# Need to refresh page everytime I go to a 'new' form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a form with client and server side validations using the model and html5 as seen in the code. Everything is working fine, but everytime e click in the link "New Ingredient" and I fill the form below it doesn't work. Moreover, it only works if I refresh the page.
Why it's not working at first?

ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :meal_ingredients 
  has_many :meals, through: :meal_ingredient 
  before_save { self.name = name.capitalize } 

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 25 }, uniqueness: true 
  validates :unit, presence: true validates :carb, :prot, :fat, numericality: true, 
                   length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 5 } 
end
```

**/new.html.erb**

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class= "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 well">
    <table class= "table">
      <%= form_for @ingredient do |f| %>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= f.label "Nome" %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= f.label "Unidade" %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= f.label "Carbo" %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= f.label "Prot" %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= f.label "Gordura" %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= f.label "kcal" %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td scope="row" class="col-md-5">
              <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3">
              <%= f.text_field :unit, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
              <%= f.text_field :carb, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
              <%= f.text_field :prot, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
              <%= f.text_field :fat, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfooter>
          <tr>
            <td class="pull-right">
              <%= f.submit @ingredient.new_record? ? 'Create Ingredient' : 'Edit Ingredient', class: "btn btn-success" %>
            </td>
            <td>
              <%= link_to "Voltar", ingredients_path, class: "btn btn-warning" %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfooter>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**/ingredients_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @ingredient = Ingredient.new
  end

  def create
    @ingredient = Ingredient.new(ingredient_params)
    @ingredient.kcal = @ingredient.carb * 4 + @ingredient.prot * 4 + @ingredient.fat * 9
    if @ingredient.save

      flash[:success] = "Ingrediente criado com sucesso"
      redirect_to ingredients_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might want to look into a nested form gem, like `cocoon`, for this.  That way the user can create all the ingredients at one time. Just a thought

Comment: Can you post the model code?

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank's! I'm gonna check for that!

Comment: @DamianoStoffie

<pre>    class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meal_ingredients
  has_many :meals, through: :meal_ingredient
  
  before_save { self.name = name.capitalize }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 25 }, uniqueness: true
  validates :unit, presence: true
  validates :carb, :prot, :fat, numericality: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 5 }
end
<code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably being caused by Turbolinks, which "speeds" up loading time by refreshing small parts of the DOM without reloading the whole entire page. As such, you'll need to trigger your script with an event that accounts for a partial refresh:

Try wrapping your JS in this:

```
var ready;

ready = function() {
  # Your code here
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on("page:load", ready);
```

Here it is in CoffeeScript:

```
ready = ->

  # Your code here

$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

You can also disable Turbolinks from your "New Ingredient" link, which will cause the entire form page to be reloaded:

```
<%= link_to('New Ingredient', ..., data: { no_turbolink: true }) %>
```

Comment: Making changes to the js didn't work, but disabling the Turbolinks from the link worked perfectly! Thank's bro!
By the way, how much it affects the perfomance of my website?